# Loopback 2.8: Check user status before every request to api

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to check user status before every request to api and return 403, if it's inactive user.

I tried to perform check in wildcarded `beforeRemote`, but I have to register it for every model to which I want restrict access.

Also it's possible to register express middleware, but `req.accessToken` doesn't exist to that moment.

Are there better ways to restrict user access?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can try to introduce a new role ACTIVE_USER and use ACLs to control access. Some documentation links: [roles](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Defining+and+using+roles) and [access control concepts](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Authentication+and+authorization).

Comment: Good solution but it doesn't work for me. After registering  `inactive` role (wildcarded DENY), I check debug output by running `$ DEBUG=loopback:security:acl slc run`. `inactive` role (with score 7511) is overlaped by `$owner` role (with score 8016). This is how the acl priority is computed.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a simple express middleware for that?

```
app.use(function checkIfUserIsActive(req, res, next) {
if (!req.accessToken) {
    // User not logged in
    return next();
}
app.models.UserModel.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        // Error with finding the user
        return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
    }
    if (!user.active) {
        return next(new Error('User is inactive.'));
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Register a role resolver. See my example here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/server/boot/create-role-resolver.js

Comment: Thanks for response, but it doesn't works for me, because another role resolvers (like $owner) have a larger computed priority then than a new one.

Comment: rejecting in a roleResolver will result in a 401 too.